# wicked_pdf gem doesn't render text

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I'm using wicked_pdf gem to show some reports, when I'm using it without styling it works ok, I have some tables in html and need some styling to them, when I'm applying the styling via wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag it displays styled tables but without text in them, when I'm using the debug mode the output looks ok,with styling and text

here is my code:

```
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render :pdf => "#{@company.name}_company_report",
               :disposition => 'attachment',
               :layout => 'reports.html.erb'
      end
   end
```

in layout I have:

```
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "reports" %>
```

and in reports.css.scss the same css I use for html view

that's how it looks in the debug mode: http://screencloud.net/v/DY2d
and this is the generated pdf: http://screencloud.net/v/7bq6

Comment: When you say "without text in them" - is there literally no text or is it that the text is the same color as the background?  Can you copy-paste any text out of the table in question?

Comment: It seems to be no text, I added
body {
  color: black !important;
}
to my css file but it has no effect